# Where is the "translatable" Schema field setting stored?

Tags: 2011, translation-manager

With Translation Manager installed you can set translatable fields in (regular, Embeddable, Multimedia, Metadata or Bundle metadata if on Tridion 2013) Schemas.

**Where or how is the selection stored when I save a schema?** Is that an AppData setting Content Manager-side or perhaps in the Translation Manager integration itself?

We're working with Support, but I'm seeing a scenario on Tridion 2011 with Translation Manager where schema changes seem to take hours for certain changes, but seconds when making a single field. It's possibly a browser issue as server and database logs apparently don't reveal any issues.

I understand Analysis (ANL) files only apply to previous SDL TMS versions (before TMS 2011 SP1). It looks like this is only for how jobs are sent, but would the optional `<ItemTypes>` settings in TranslationManager.xml have any impact on saving Schema configuration?

**Update**: apparently avoiding changing lists (e.g. text set to a Category) or embedded schema avoids the delay. Strange but you can't set translation for those anyways. For lists, the child versions selections don't change with managed translation, but we can translate keywords. We set the translation options for embedded fields in the embeddable schema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This information stored in schema itself (in CM DB)

This is standart CM extension point for schemas

in schema XSD it looks like this

```
 <xsd:element name="NewField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:normalizedString">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <tcm:ExtensionXml xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
                        <FieldInfo translate="yes" xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/TranslationManager" />
                    </tcm:ExtensionXml>
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
```

You can see it in Source tab of schema

Comment: Ah ok, this is the same approach the [FBI extension](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/fbi) uses.

Comment: @AlvinReyes more like the other way around, FBI uses the same approach as TM ;)